# Apparent Grizzly Memory Leak - HTTP requests and responses

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jersey, grizzly

Recently, an application that I developed has started using significantly more memory than usual. It's a standalone Jersey REST webapp that runs periodic data processing jobs. I was afraid that the size of data I was processing had suddenly spiked, so I took a heap dump, threw it in Eclipse MAT, and got these results:

[image: Oh, all of the memory is being used by a memory manager. Great.]

All of the memory is being consumed by a `PooledMemoryManager`, in the form of `byte[]`s. When I examine these bytes, they overwhelmingly look like they contain the text of HTTP requests and responses:

[image: GETs and OKs for days]

I expect the application to field a lot of these requests, about once per thirty seconds, as my monitoring service pings its healthcheck endpoint. However, there are about 30,000 of these strings stored in 4KB blocks that haven't been freed, as oldgen space starts running low and my application crashes.

I'm at a loss to explain this behavior; it started happening about a week after my most recent deployment, but it only takes about a day to consume the entire heap, and none of the code that I've deployed in the past several months comes *near* touching Jersey or Grizzly code.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before?

Comment: Have you checked your `PooledMemoryManager` parameters? Maybe something stands out: https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/memory/PooledMemoryManager.html

Comment: Reading the source code of PooledMemoryManger, it seems that by default it preallocate 10% of max JVM memory, which is split evenly in 3 pools, each with `byte[]` size of 4K, 16K, 64K. This number matches your graph where 31k instances of `byte[]` accounts for 290M memory.

Comment: If that's the case, these memory slots are allocated at the start of application, and persist throughout the life of JVM. They are probably not the source of your problem. While 300M is a lot of memory, and we question such aggressive usage, it is not *that* much on today's machines.

Comment: @Zhong_Yu It would appear that you are correct; I was so focused on the percentage that I failed to notice that this only accounted for about 300M of the 2.8 GB memory that `top` says my process is using. Perhaps I am running into a garbage-collection issue, since the vast majority of my heap appears to be unreachable.

Comment: Well, a big cache is always the enemy of GC, since GC needs to periodically iterate through it to mark live/dead objects. In your case, I don't know whether 30k long-lived objects can be a problem for GC. But anyways, it is really really wrong for grizzly to try to pool `byte[]`. If you can, try significantly reduce the pool capacity.

Comment: You can switch to the HeapMemoryManager or provide your own implementation if the PooledMemoryManager isn't to your taste.  Note the PooledMemoryManager does provide several tuning options to control how much heap it will use.